# Revolution Slider not working anymore after upgrade from Contao 4.4 to 4.9

Tags: revolution-slider, contao

After my contao upgrade attempt from 4.4 to 4.9 the revolution slider plugin stoped working. I also don't see it in the contao-manager and [this page](https://shop.codefog.pl/product/slider-revolution.html) suggests, that it was maybe installed manually?

The current version is 4.6.4 (26.11.2014) tested for the ancient jquery 1.9

Anybody knows something about this and has a hint if it can be fixed?

Comment: Are you using a purchased theme from PCT? I think they also use a version of the revolution slider: https://www.premium-contao-themes.com/revolution-slider-5-2530.html

Comment: As far as I can tell, it's a custom theme - I think I simply use slick slider instead...

Comment: Actually I see quite some pct_something folders. I guess you're right!

Comment: In that case - you need to follow PCT's official instructions on how to update a PCT installation from 4.4. to 4.9. At the very least you will also need to manually update all PCT modules in `system/modules/` as far as I know. You can download the latest version in the customer section of PCT.

Comment: Hi @fritzmg, would you like to add your comment here as answer, os I can accept it?

Comment: Added it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out you are using a "Premium Contao Themes" theme - thus you need to follow PCT's official instructions on how to update a PCT installation from 4.4. to 4.9. At the very least you will need to manually update all PCT modules in `system/modules/` as far as I know. You can download the latest version in the customer section of PCT.